# Exporting Snowflake Query Results in Google Drive as a Spreadsheet

Tags: sql, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow-scheduler

Is there a way where I can export the Snowflake query results into Google Drive as a Spreadsheet using Python.
I need to automate this process using Airflow.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You can download the results from Snowflake using Python + Panda (data frames). The sample code is provided here: https://docs.coveo.com/en/m2hg0593/analyze-usage-data/use-case-retrieve-data-with-the-python-connector

As for doing the upload to G-Drive, it would need to be done by leveraging the google developer API and again using Panda.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SnowflakeOperator to unload directly into GCS
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-gcs.html
https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/snowflake/modules/snowflakeoperator

and then there is a GCSToGoogleSheets operator
https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/google/modules/gcstogooglesheetsoperator